# Error in opening text file from src folder in Java

Tags: java, file-io, iostream

I am making a Java program and want to open a `text(notepad)` file ,that i have saved in `src` folder in my Java Program, I have tried to do it by the following code , but it is giving error. "The method `exec(String)` in the type `Runtime` is not applicable for the arguments
`(InputStream)` , Any suggestions ? Thanks

```
Runtime runtime = Runtime.getRuntime();
InputStream lic = this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("MyFile.txt");
Process process = runtime.exec(lic);
```

Comment: Are you trying to literally open Notepad, or do you want to read the file into your program?

Comment: @Jeremy Heiler I have saved some text in "MyFile.txt" and want to open that text file(With the text in it)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not execute an input-stream, it's just a collection of bytes, not a file.

You should store this file somewhere else inside your project (like a resources folder) and use the path to open the file. Here's how it would look like:

```
File file = new File("resources/my-file.txt");
String[] command = { "notepad.exe", file.getAbsolutePath() };
Runtime.getRuntime().exec( command );
```

Answer (score 1):

None of the `Runtime.exec` methods accept an `InputStream`

http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Runtime.html

---

To read a file from an `InputStream`, use a [`BufferedReader`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/BufferedReader.html)

```
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(lic));

String line = reader.readLine()
while(line != null){
    System.out.println(line);
    line = reader.readLine();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you're trying to do:

```
ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("notepad", "/path/to/text-file");
Process process = pb.start();
```

See [`ProcessBuilder`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html) Javadocs.